# Dictionaries not found when using MahApps.Metro

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary, mahapps.metro

I just created a new project and got the MahApps.Metro from nuget. I added this to my App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

But I get one error like this for each ResourceDictionary entry:

```
An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary     "pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml".
```

But the dictionaries are found because when I run the application the styles are being applied to the controls. It seems to be a design time only error.

Is there any way to hide them? I'm also having errors for each MahApps Style property that I have set in my XAMLs. Since it's a big application my Error List always has ~30 errors.

This is really annoying, because the styles are being applied when the applicatino run, so there's nothing wrong. When I have a real error it turns in a hell to find it in the middle of all of these other 'erros'

Comment: I have the same issue with Mahapps when I add another package (cefsharp) in my application. I can run my app and don't find the reason. I use Mahapps on five app and it's the first time it give me this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same error if i don't have checked "Run project code in XAML Designer (if supported)". Maybe it is a problem.

[image: Run project code in XAML Designer (if supported)]

Comment: This option doesn't exists in VS2017.